# Does the relative position matter for the equality of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I was reading the Linear Algebra book by *Friedberg, Insel and Spence*. Initially they have given the definition of a vector as:

> Many familiar physical notions, such as forces, velocities, and accelerations,
> involve both a magnitude (the amount of the force, velocity, or acceleration)
> and a direction. Any such entity involving both magnitude and direction is
> called a “vector.” A vector is represented by an arrow whose length denotes
> the magnitude of the vector and whose direction represents the direction of
> the vector. In most physical situations involving vectors, only the magnitude
> and direction of the vector are significant; consequently, we regard vectors
> with the same magnitude and direction as being equal irrespective of their
> positions.

I want to know whether relative position matters or not for the equality of two vectors, I mean, if two vectors with the same magnitude and direction but at different position according to the coordinate system then will we "always" say that these two vectors are equal ? Is there any situation or theory where we don't consider these two vectors as equal if they differ in position in the space.

Can anyone please help me ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How could the relative position of two vectors matter when position of either doesn't (the definition clearly says so). If you want to you can move one of them (but as @jason's answer says, a vector doesn't have a start point, so it's pointless), but then the relative position to a fixed point (where you might - pointlessly - imagine the other vector fixed).

Comment: Thanks @Henriksupportsthecommunity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors by definition contain only the information of magnitude and direction, not of a point of reference, or "start point". The theory of affine spaces is what you are referring to. In that theory, you use the extra information of starting point. As in a 2d affine space, you need three points to define it, two for direction and one starting point.